# Why autovacuum is not running

Tags: postgresql, performance, autovacuum

If the parameter `autovacuum` is `on`, and the parameter `track_counts` is `on` also - why it's look like the autovacuum has never worked?

```
select relname,last_vacuum, last_autovacuum, last_analyze, last_autoanalyze 
from pg_stat_user_tables 
where last_vacuum is not null 
or last_autovacuum is not null;
```

no rows...

Which actions needed to make it run?

My version is : PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: Have you actually changed (updated, deleted, inserted) rows in those tables? If yes, more than the threshold for autovacuum? Do you have any connections that have the state "idle in transaction"?

Comment: yeah, create a table insert a few thousand rows (use generate_series()) delete (or update) some or all of those rows, then wait a bit.

Comment: Did you change any autovacuum settings from the default values? Are there autovacuum workers running? Do you get any messages if you set `log_autovacuum_min_duration = 0`?

Comment: I take 1 table as example - in the last week, more than 160K rows inserted.. the parameters : autovacuum_vacuum_threshold, autovacuum_analyze_threshold both set to 50.. I didn't change anything from the default. I don't know if someone else did..

Comment: I assume you can post result of `select setting, name from pg_settings where source <> 'default' and name like '%vacuum%';` also do you have any rows after removing `where` at all?..

Comment: results of query: 30000, log_autovacuum_min_duration. and yes I have there a lot of tables.

Comment: anybody? this is a production env.. changes in volumns happens all the time.. how can I ensure that the autovacuum will run??

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#:%7E:text=6.-,The%20Autovacuum%20Daemon,inserted%2C%20updated%20or%20deleted%20tuples.)

Postgres AutoVacuum will run when `num_obselete_tuples` exceeds the `vacuum_threshold`.

`vacuum_threshold = base_threshold + (scale_factor * num_tuples)`

- `base_threshold` = `autovacuum_vacuum_threshold`
- `scale_factor` = `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor`
- `num_tuples` can be found by querying `pg_class`

```
SELECT relname, reltuples FROM pg_class
```

You should be able to use the numbers above to determine how many `dead_tuples` are required before the autovacuum will start.

You can see the `n_dead_tuples` with:

```
SELECT n_dead_tup FROM pg_stat_user_tables where relname = ‘transaction’;
```

A `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement will create a `dead_tuple`. You can check the `autovacuum` settings and plug numbers in to find the `autovacuum threshold` and then update that many rows in your table which ought to trigger the autovacuum daemon.

You can look for running autovacuum processes with:

```sql
SELECT query, xact_start, state FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE query LIKE 'autovacuum:%';
```